# Saving data to seprate csv files in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I made a **scraper** for yellow pages. There is a categories.txt file that is read by the script and then it generates links according to those categories:

```
settings = get_project_settings()
categories = settings.get('CATEGORIES')



    links = []
    
    for category in categories:
        link = 'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=' + category + '&geo_location_terms=NY&page=1'
        links.append(link)
```

then this links list is passed to start urls:

```
class YpSpider(CrawlSpider):

    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        super().__init__(*a, **kw)
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    name = 'yp'
    allowed_domains = ['yellowpages.com']
    
    start_urls = links

      rules = (

    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//a[@class="business-name"]', allow=''), callback='parse_item',
         follow=True),

    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//a[@class="next ajax-page"]', allow=''),
         follow=True),
)
```

it will save all the data from all the links in a csv file named parent.csv. This parent.csv file will have a column named keyword which will help in seperating data from different categories and make seperate csv files for each of them. This is implemented in spider closed function:

```
def spider_closed(self, spider):
    with open('parent.csv', 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            with open('{}.csv'.format(row[0]), 'a') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow(row)
```

The problem i am facing is to get the category name in my parse method corresponding to every link so that it may be saved in parent.csv and used to seperate diiferent categories afterwards:

```
def parse_item(self, response):

    item = YellowItem()

    item['keyword'] = # here i need the corresponding category for every link
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change the way you generate links. You can, for example, override the [start_requests](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) method and pass the category to the request through either it's [cb_kwargs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=cb_kwargs#scrapy.http.Response.cb_kwargs) or [meta](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=cb_kwargs#scrapy.http.Request.meta) attribute.
I would also suggest, that you change the implementation to get the settings from the crawler calling the spider by overriding [from_crawler](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=from_crawler#scrapy.spiders.Spider.from_crawler).
Here's how I would do it:

```py
class YpSpider(CrawlSpider):
    def __init__(self, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.crawler = crawler
        self.categories = crawler.settings.get('CATEGORIES')

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler)

    def start_requests(self):
        for category in self.categories:
            yield Request(
                f'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms={category}&geo_location_terms=NY&page=1',
                self.parse,
                cb_kwargs={'category': category}
            )

    def parse(self, response, category):
        # do sth
        ...
        for url in response.xpath('//a[@class="business-name"]/@href').extract():
            yield Request(
                url, 
                self.parse_item, 
                cb_kwargs={'category': category}
            )
        yield Request(
            response.xpath('//a[@class="next ajax-page"]/@href').extract_first(),
            self.parse,
            cb_kwargs={'category': category}
        )

    def parse_item(self, response, category):
        item = YellowItem()
        item['keyword'] = category
        # do sth else
        ...
```

Comment: throws a type error : current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
TypeError: parse_item() got an unexpected keyword argument 'category'

how can i solve this?

Comment: @rexsphinx True, sorry. I've corrected it in the example. The mistake was that you would need to specify category as parameter for parse_item.

Comment: but this doesnt work. I have rules defined too, and those don't work like this

Comment: @rexsphinx Then you should maybe consider giving enough information on your problem so that somebody can help you with it.

Comment: its just that there are rules defined too...nothing else....i have added those in the question

Comment: I still don't get it. The [source](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/_modules/scrapy/spiders/crawl.html#Rule) as well as the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule)  suggest, that cb_kwargs pretty much works the same there. The problem seems to be more how to pass the right category for the rule.

Comment: of course the problem is to pass the right category thats what the question is

Comment: Then I guess you shouldn't use rules but yield requests instead. I've edited the answer to show what I mean.

Comment: although it works somehow...but there is still an error: AttributeError: 'YpSpider' object has no attribute 'crawler'
if u would help with it it will be great

Comment: If you just add `self.crawler = crawler` to `__init__`, does it work then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214366/discussion-between-rex-sphinx-and-patrick-k).